# In Lua, how to find particular string in url ?

Tags: string, url, lua

I'm writing a Lua function, and I want to add a if/else statement if url has particular string for example "home", if url look like this:

```
http://AAA/home
http://AAA/home/01
http://AAA/home/02
```

Then stop the function, but if url doesn't have "home" string, then do the function:

```
http://AAA/next
http://AAA/test
```

Can anyone give me some clue about detecting the particular string in url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:
You can use `string.match()` or `string.find()`, I personally use `string.find()` (most people do).

Your code would look something like this:

```html
text = "http://AAA/home"

if string.find(text, "home?",0,true) then
  # do what you want
else
  # do something else
end
```

PS : Duplicated question - [How to check if matching text is found in a string in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158450/how-to-check-if-matching-text-is-found-in-a-string-in-lua)

Comment: Whenever you use string.find, be aware that the string searching for is a regex - so searching for "home?" would match "hom" too. To avoid this, use string.find(text, "home?",0,true) to signify it's a plain string [see the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.find)