# How do i find if a specific string is present inside an instance name?

Tags: roblox

For example, I'm trying to find every instance in Workspace that has "Ragdoll" in the name, but the ragdoll names vary and there are several of them. Here's my script so far:

```
for i,v in pairs(workspace:GetChildren()) do
  if v --[[script to find string inside instance name goes here]] then
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

While I know neither lua nor Roblox, it looks from [this example](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/GetChildren) in the Roblox API reference that each element in the result of `workspace:GetChildren()` has a `Name`. As such, you should be able to do something like the following to determine if `"Ragdoll"` is a substring of each name:

```lua
local children = workspace:GetChildren()
for i, child in ipairs(children) do
    if string.find(child.Name, "Ragdoll") then
       -- (do stuff)
    end
end
```

See also [How to check if matching text is found in a string in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10158450/12162258).