Is it possible to Lua match string with an image name?
I got this script
door = script.Parent
function onChatted(msg, recipient, speaker) 
source = string.lower(speaker.Name) 
msg = string.lower(msg) 
-- thecharacter = script.Parent.TheCharacter
if (msg == string.match(File.name)) then 
door.CanCollide = false 
door.Transparency = 0.7 
wait(4) 
door.CanCollide = true 
door.Transparency = 0 
end 
end 
game.Players.ChildAdded:connect(function(plr)
plr.Chatted:connect(function(msg, recipient) onChatted(msg, recipient, plr) end) 
end)


Is it possible to match the user msg with an image name instead of a character?
I m new to lua and can t seem to find anything about this.

If in msg you have the file name, and in File.name the full name of the file and you want to shorten it, then try extracting the name like this:
string.match(File.name,"([^/]*)$")

It matches: a string, starting from the end, and then captures any characters that's not /.

You can set the keyword to the door:
door.Keyword = "sesame"
And than just check it:
if (msg == door.Keyword) then
-- open the door for 4 seconds

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10158547/12968803
